# Flask & SQL Alchemy db.create_all() detect unicode returns: %r

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to setup a sqlite database with Flask using SQLAlchemy according to [the tutorial:](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world)

I get the following error when I try to run `db.create_all()`:

```
(venv)[username@md projectname]$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Jan 12 2015, 10:50:37) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from app import db
/home/username/flask-project/projectname/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:800: UserWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True to suppress this warning.
  warnings.warn('SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True to suppress this warning.')
>>> db.create_all()
/home/username/flask-project/projectname/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:298: SAWarning: Exception attempting to detect unicode returns: OperationalError('(sqlite3.OperationalError) near "\xf1\x90\x81\x93\xf1\x90\x81\x8c\xf5\x80\x81\x83\xf0\xb0\x80\xa0\xf4\xb0\x81\x81\xfa\x80\x81\x94\xfd\x80\x80\xa7\xfc\xb0\x81\xa5\xf8\x80\x81\xb4\xfb\x80\x81\xb0\xfa\x90\x81\xa1\xf8\x80\x81\xae\xf9\x90\x81\xb2\xfd\x90\x81\xb4\xfb\xa0\x81\xb2\xf9\xb0\x81\xb3\xf0\x90\x80\xa0\xf8\x80\x81\x93\xf0\x90\x81\x96\xf0\xb0\x81\x92\xf0\x90\x81\x88\xfa\x80\x81\x92\xfc\x80\x80\xb6\xfa\x90\x80\xa9\xf0\x90\x80\xa0\xf8\x80\x81\x93\xfb\xa0\x81\xa1\xfb\xa0\x81\xaf\xfc\x90\x81\x9f\xfe\x90\x80\x80": syntax error',)
  "detect unicode returns: %r" % de)
/home/username/flask-project/projectname/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:298: SAWarning: Exception attempting to detect unicode returns: OperationalError('(sqlite3.OperationalError) near "\xf1\x90\x81\x93\xf1\x90\x81\x8c\xf5\x80\x81\x83\xf0\xb0\x80\xa0\xf4\xb0\x81\x81\xfa\x80\x81\x94\xfd\x80\x80\xa7\xfc\xb0\x81\xa5\xf8\x80\x81\xb4\xfb\xa0\x81\xb5\xf8\xb0\x81\xa9\xf9\x80\x81\xaf\xf8\x80\x81\xa5\xf9\x90\x81\xb2\xfd\x90\x81\xb4\xfb\xa0\x81\xb2\xf9\xb0\x81\xb3\xf0\x90\x80\xa0\xf8\x80\x81\x93\xf0\x90\x81\x96\xf0\xb0\x81\x92\xf0\x90\x81\x88\xfa\x80\x81\x92\xfc\x80\x80\xb6\xfa\x90\x80\xa9\xf0\x90\x80\xa0\xf8\x80\x81\x93\xfb\xa0\x81\xa1\xfb\xa0\x81\xaf\xfc\x90\x81\x9f\xfc\xa0\x80\x80": syntax error',)
  "detect unicode returns: %r" % de)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/username/flask-project/projectname/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 972, in create_all
    self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
  File "/home/username/flask-project/projectname/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 964, in _execute_for_all_tables
    op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
  File "/home/username/flask-project/projectname/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 3695, in create_all
    tables=tables)
  File "/home/username/flask-project/projectname/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1855, in _run_visitor
    with self._optional_conn_ctx_manager(connection) as conn:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/home/username/flask-project/projectname/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1848, in _optional_conn_ctx_manager
    with self.contextual_connect() as conn:
  File "/home/username/flask-project/projectname/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2039, in contextual_connect
    self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, None),
  File "/home/username/flask-project/projectname/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2078, in _wrap_pool_connect
    e, dialect, self)
  File "/home/username/flask-project/projectname/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1405, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    exc_info
  File "/home/username/flask-project/projectname/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 200, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/home/username/flask-project/projectname/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2074, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/home/username/flask-project/projectname/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 376, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/home/username/flask-project/projectname/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 713, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/home/username/flask-project/projectname/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 480, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/home/username/flask-project/projectname/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 1151, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/home/username/flask-project/projectname/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 323, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/home/username/flask-project/projectname/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 454, in __init__
    exec_once(self.connection, self)
  File "/home/username/flask-project/projectname/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py", line 246, in exec_once
    self(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/username/flask-project/projectname/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/event/attr.py", line 256, in __call__
    fn(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/username/flask-project/projectname/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 1319, in go
    return once_fn(*arg, **kw)
  File "/home/username/flask-project/projectname/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 165, in first_connect
    dialect.initialize(c)
  File "/home/username/flask-project/projectname/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 256, in initialize
    self._check_unicode_description(connection):
  File "/home/username/flask-project/projectname/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 343, in _check_unicode_description
    ]).compile(dialect=self)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "???????3???￥": syntax error
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have an issue with these characters:

```
???????3???￥
```

It is unclear based on what you've posted where those are, but it's likely in the file you're using to build your database from. The characters in that file need to be in a character encoding that can be interpreted.